# Access x509 certificates in windows service certificate stores with C#

Tags: c#, security, x509certificate2

I would like to store an x509 certificate for use by a windows service. The problem I am having is where to store this certificate. It seems using the microsoft management console (mmc) certificate snap-in that you can have windows service specific certificate stores. The trouble is I cannot figure out how to get at these certificates via C#.

- Installed a certificate under the service store using mmc and the certificate snap-in.

Created and installed a windows service using [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/getting-started) with this code:

```
var localStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine); 
localStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
foreach (X509Certificate2 c in localStore.Certificates)
{
    _log.Debug("local: certificate for {0} - has private key {1}".ToFormat(c.SubjectName.Name, c.HasPrivateKey));
}

var userStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser); 
userStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
foreach (X509Certificate2 c in userStore.Certificates)
{
    _log.Debug("user: certificate for {0} - has private key {1}".ToFormat(c.SubjectName.Name, c.HasPrivateKey));
}
```

Never do I see the certificate in the windows service's store. If I add the certificate to the Local Computer certificate store the Windows service does see the certificate.

All that fancy tooling in mmc to add certificates to service stores has to have a purpose.

Answer (score 3):

The windows service is running under a different user account than you are when running MMC, that's why you do not see the certificate in the CurrentUser store; but do see it in the LocalMachine store.

One way of solving this, is to have the windows service running as a specific user, say 'ServiceX'.  Then you run MMC as 'ServiceX' and add the certificate into the current user store.

Comment: Thank you but I realize this. Basic stuff. What I am concerned about is that MMC goes through great pains to support adding certificates in the context of a Windows Service. How do I get access to these certs from the service?